Variable data gets cleared to value of 0 at the end of every for loop iteration
This is the code which I had a problem with:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int K;
    string commands;

    fstream fileIn("robotin.txt");
    fileIn >> K >> commands;

    fileIn.close();

    int updown = 0;
    int sides = 0;

    for(char i : commands){
        //cout << i << "   " << typeid(i).name() << endl;

        switch(i){
            case 'N': 
                updown +=1; 
                cout << updown << endl;                
            case 'S': 
                updown -=1;
            case 'E': 
                sides  +=1;
            case 'W': 
                sides  -=1;
        }

        cout << "Updown is " << updown << endl 
             << "Sides is "  << sides  << endl 
             << endl;   
    }

    fstream fileOut("robotout.txt");
    
    fileOut <<  abs(updown) + abs(sides);

    fileOut.close();

    return 0;
}

the file input is as follows:
5
ENNEE

It can be noticed that the value does change properly during every iteration however it gets reset by the end of every iteration
I was expecting the value to permanently change at the end of every iteration so I could get the total value at the end of the for loop.
However the variable values kept resetting to a value of 0 at the end of every iteration. This resulted in the variables values after the loop finished to be 0.

Your switch cases fall through. You have missed one important keyword. I suggest that you repeat your learning materials

OK, so if the input is a count of the number of characters in a string, and then the string itself, you're supposed to be using a for loop with a loop variable, not a foreach (which is what the for(char i is).  That's why the input includes a count of the number of characters.

sides  and updown shouldn't be set to 0 every time but it will be unexpected because of the problem in your switch case that @3CxEZiVlQ mentioned.

Do a test with some of the letters either 'S' or 'W' and you will see different behaviour.    And that difference will be a consequence of the actual problem too - your switch case is falling through cases, rather than executing each in isolation  [this is an example of how C++ differs from some other languages].   Goes to show your test case is inadequate.      You might also want to have a test case with some random letter (that isn't a compass cardinal direction) to determine if your code handles bad input appropriately.

Please show both the output that you are expecting and the output you are actually getting.

It can help if to turn on warnings on your compiler: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5a7f069ee16a7fe4

You aren't breaking after each case in your switch. This results in fall-through. Wherever execution starts in your switch, it doesn't stop until it hits a break or the end of the switch.
In the event of 'N', all statements in the switch are executed, and the 'S' case undoes the 'N' case. Similarly, in the event of 'E', the 'W' case is also executed.
Invoking your compiler with warnings turned on/up should warn about this, or cause errors if you use -Werror (or it's equivalent.)
Had you tested with 'S' or 'W' characters in your string, you would have seen a different result.
        switch (i) {
            case 'N': 
                updown += 1; 
                break;                
            case 'S': 
                updown -= 1;
                break;
            case 'E': 
                sides += 1;
                break;
            case 'W': 
                sides -= 1;
                break;
        }

Further, you may wish to provide a default case to handle unexpected characters in the input.
